# Como criar extensão no Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensão

Como criar uma extensão no Firefox?

Quero desenvolver uma extensão para uso pessoal, como é desenvolvida uma extensão no Firefox, com javascript, estrutura de pastas e arquivos no diretorio da mozilla, como funciona isso?

Quero saber o necessário para eu começar a criação de uma extensão, para eu ter um encaminhamento, direcionamento nesse novo projeto.

Comment: Veja este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: @lazyFox Eu vi isso, mas vi também que é de 2009, o quanto isso pode ser antigo ou desatualizado? :(

Comment: Actualizei o link